# How to stop certain classes from being generated in OpenApi generator?

Tags: openapi-generator

I am using OpenApi generator to create server code (jaxrs-jersey).
I want to prevent certain classes from being generated.

In my specific case, for each api I want only some of the classes to be generated.

I know you can create a custom generator, but most of code generated by the default jaxrs-jersey generator is good for me, so I rather keep using the default one.

Is there a way to accomplish it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation in https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/customization.md#bringing-your-own-models

```
Sometimes you don't want a model generated. In this case, you can simply specify an import mapping to tell the codegen what not to create. When doing this, every location that references a specific model will refer back to your classes. Note, this may not apply to all languages...

To specify an import mapping, use the --import-mappings argument and specify the model-to-import logic as such:

--import-mappings Pet=my.models.MyPet

Or for multiple mappings:

--import-mappings Pet=my.models.MyPet,Order=my.models.MyOrder

or

--import-mappings Pet=my.models.MyPet --import-mappings Order=my.models.MyOrder
```

I applied the above like following in maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                       
                            
                            <importMappings>Comment=com.example.project.Comment</importMappings>
                            <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                            <library>resttemplate</library>
                            
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

So in my example, I have a class named "Comment" that is auto generated incorrectly by openapi generator. So I created the Comment class myself, into the above path "com.example.Comment" in importMappings field. And I passed it as a parameter into the importMappings field just like above. After above setup, Comment class is not generated by openapi-generator anymore and my Comment class is not overriden